# Visual Studio being weird with Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, intellisense

I have freshly installed Visual Studio 2019 with Python v3.9.
I am getting these weird issues as in the screenshot below for e.g. with:

```py
    print("foo", end="")
```

Visual Studio is having a problem with the '`end=""`' part as if it's not supported.
Running the code works totally fine.

I've only now started with Python and these are the only two problems yet I've stumbled upon. I assume there's more.

**Screenshot of problem:**

[image: Screenshot of Visual Studio showing the error: "'as' requires Python 2.6 or later", while later versions of Python are installed.]

Comment: Your image doesn't match the mentioned code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Although** python 3x adds [the new feature](https://realpython.com/lessons/sep-end-and-flush/) about `sep`, `end`, and `flush` arguments for print`()`, it still does not support the Intellisense for those arguments.

Also, if I changed to use `Python 3.9`, I faced the error that it did not support `sep`, `end`, and `flush` arguments.

[image]

**However**, when I changed to use `Python 3.8`, it works well and not sure it is an issue with `Python 3.9`.

[image]

**Besides**, **Python** just provides a text description of the use of these arguments, which requires you to write manually according to its specifications, rather than direct Intellisense for them and automatically pop up.

[image]

**When** you use it, it works well:

[image]

**Conclusion**

The problem is that **Python** does not provide the Intellisense for `sep`, `end`, and `flush` arguments so far.

I think you can contact with [the python product team](https://www.python.org/psf/#id3) or the [VS Team](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with your code but with your interpreter.
Set your interpreter to 3.9 and save and it should work fine.

If that doesn't work, try restarting VSCode.

Comment: it seems to me that the screenshot shows it has already been done.

Comment: It looks like the VSCode hasn't recognized the env at all for running that file.

Comment: also, OP apparently uses Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.